# Java GPU implementation

Tags: java, opengl, gpu, jfreechart, jogl

I use JFreeChart to build plots and I decided to use OpenGL (jogl) to increase speed of app. For example, I have this function that draw splines:

```
@Override
protected void drawFirstPassShape(Graphics2D g2, int pass, int series,
                                  int item, Shape shape) {
    g2.setStroke(getItemStroke(series, item));
    g2.setPaint(getItemPaint(series, item));
    g2.draw(shape);
}
```

How can I turn it into **Jogl** function? Or maybe I need to use another library?

Answer (score 1):

The clean, but painful solution would be to replace all occurrences/usages/functionality of `Graphics2D` with Jogl ones. (Sorry if I don't get too detailed here/yet.)

[This bridge](http://brandonborkholder.github.io/glg2d/:) promises to achieve your goals by very few (configuration&coding + license) expense:

> It's very easy to get started using GLG2D. As a library, GLG2D is designed to wrap your existing rendering code. If you're using Java2D to render, most likely you're rendering a scene into a some instance of JComponent. In order to render your scene using OpenGL instead of Java2D, just wrap your JComponent inside a GLG2DCanvas.

Do you have one place (the few the better), where you can "wrap your JComponent"?

Comment: uff, it's a good question. I think I must overwrite some functions in JFreeChart to "wrap my JComponent". Thanks for answer, I will try!

Comment: I don't think you must go that far, where does the `g2` come from? From where the `shape`? "JComponent" is also a veery broad meaning! ;) ..sorry I don't even know, whether you run on a web/desktop/mobile/(embedded:) environment? And Jeffr'y (JFreeChart) is like the "Swiss Army Knife" in (free) charting software.

Comment: There is a function that I wrote in this post, it's draw my plots. I decided to overwrite it but I don't know how to use **GG2D** here. **JFreeChart** has a lot of intern functions that help to make a lot of things easily and it faster than xChart, GraL etc. I use NetBeans IDE